# How can I make my sticky header be transparent to the background but not to the images and text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have a page with a radial-gradient as a background. The content is longer than the viewport and the center of this gradient is thus not in the center of the screen, which is also the desired result.
Now the problem that I have is that I also use a sticky header for navigation which is transparent so that you can not see a visible line between the header and the content, however this means that the header interferes with the text and images on the page.

Is there a way to make the header only transparent for the background image?

I have already tried setting the same background on the header but this gives a very different result, now there are two different headers. I have thought about putting the text in a scrolling div but then the background result would not cover the entire page, just the viewport.

Comment: I would recommend checking out [mcve]. That will assist you the most at this point in your question asking.

Answer (score 0):

here z-index values ensure that the overlay is below the header
adial-gradient background is applied to the .content div, ensuring it doesn't get affected by the header.i have used this before u can give try

```
 <body>
<div class="header">
<nav>
  Your navigation content here 
</nav>
</div>
<div class="header-overlay"></div>
<div class="content">
 Your main content here
</div>
 //css file//
header-overlay {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
height: 60px; /* Adjust the height of your header */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Adjust the color and transparency 
*/
z-index: 1;
}
.content {
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top left, #f06, #00f);
  }
```